# python - finding two highest values elementwise - column only returns final result of loop

Tags: python, pandas

I am relatively new to python and am in desperate need of some help.

I have a dataframe (called "waves") that contains a play-by-play list of a duel, where two persons perform scoring actions. Each action is scored between 0-10. The dataframe is sorted by the time that is left in the duel.

Example of dataset "waves":

```
    Person  Movement Score Timeleft
0    BH99    WBP16   4.73  25:43.0
1    JD21    WBP17   5.33  25:01.0
2    BH99    WBP18   5.23  23:20.0
3    BH99    WBP19   4.83  19:48.0
4    JD21    WBP20   4.83  18:26.0
5    BH99    WBP21   5.27  16:15.0
6    BH99    WBP22   1.60  12:45.0
7    JD21    WBP23   3.10  07:42.0
8    JD21    WBP24   5.07  06:36.0
9    BH99    WBP25   6.33  06:25.0
10   JD21    WBP26   0.27  03:34.0
11   BH99    WBP27   4.40  02:43.0
12   JD21    WBP28   4.57  02:29.0
```

From this dataframe I would now like to create two columns that record (elementwise) the current two high scores at the time of the action.

I came up with the following code for this

```
    #setting initial starting value for max1 and max2 to zero and creating column in datafram "waves"
max1 = 0
max2 = 0
waves["max1"]=max1
waves["max2"]=max2

#for loop to calulate highscores elementwise

for high in waves["Score"]:

    if high > max1 :
        max2 = max1
        max1 = high
        waves["max1"]=max1
        waves["max2"]=max2
        print(max1, max2)       

    elif max2 < high <= max1:
        max1 = max1
        max2 = high   
        print(max1, max2)
        waves["max1"]=max1
        waves["max2"]=max2
        
    else:     
        max1 = max1
        max2 = max2
        print(max1, max2)
        waves["max1"]=max1
        waves["max2"]=max2
       
print(waves)
```

The problem now is that the print call `print(max1, max2)` returns exactly what I want, somehow the new columns "max1" and "max2" of my waves dataframe however only contain the final (instead of the elementwise) two high scores in each row.

output of print(max1, max2) inside the for loop:

```
4.73 0
5.33 4.73
5.33 5.23
5.33 5.23
5.33 5.23
5.33 5.27
5.33 5.27
5.33 5.27
5.33 5.27
6.33 5.33
6.33 5.33
6.33 5.33
6.33 5.33
```

output of updated dataframe waves with new columns max1 & max2:

```
   Person Movement  Score Timeleft  max1  max2
0    BH99    WBP16   4.73  25:43.0  6.33  5.33
1    JD21    WBP17   5.33  25:01.0  6.33  5.33
2    BH99    WBP18   5.23  23:20.0  6.33  5.33
3    BH99    WBP19   4.83  19:48.0  6.33  5.33
4    JD21    WBP20   4.83  18:26.0  6.33  5.33
5    BH99    WBP21   5.27  16:15.0  6.33  5.33
6    BH99    WBP22   1.60  12:45.0  6.33  5.33
7    JD21    WBP23   3.10  07:42.0  6.33  5.33
8    JD21    WBP24   5.07  06:36.0  6.33  5.33
9    BH99    WBP25   6.33  06:25.0  6.33  5.33
10   JD21    WBP26   0.27  03:34.0  6.33  5.33
11   BH99    WBP27   4.40  02:43.0  6.33  5.33
12   JD21    WBP28   4.57  02:29.0  6.33  5.33
```

What am I missing here? In another thread I read that it could be connected to my indentation but was not successful adjusting it so far..

Any help is appreciated. Thank you and enjoy your day :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Track them with a list.  Add the new value, sort the list, drop the lowest.  Keep the new columns in a list, then add them to the df after the loop.

```
max1col = []
max2col = []
maxes = [0,0]

#for loop to calulate highscores elementwise

for high in waves["Score"]:
    maxes.append(high)
    maxes = sorted(maxes)[-2:]
    max1col.append(maxes[0])
    max2col.append(maxes[1])

waves["max1"]=max1col
waves["max2"]=max2col
print(waves)
```

Comment: Perfect, that works like it should and makes a lot more sense to me. Thank you!

Comment: Remember to accept the answer.